# How to write asynchronous thread classes in iOS?

Tags: ios, objective-c, asynchronous, dispatch-async

In my App I need to run more than 300 threads asynchronously [Each thread dies within 500ms] . In Android I write an ayncTask class and run my code inside of it. How Can we do in iOS, I need a class not a function.

Please Provide any example, tutorial or documentation. It will be a great help.

Comment: `NSThread`?  BTW, 300 threads is total overkill on a 4 or 8 core device.  You may wish to check into GCD and `NSOperationQueue`.

Comment: Please provide any example or tutorial or article if available. Thats a great help

Answer (score 3):

I would use GCD for this purpose, please refer to this tutorial or to apple documentation : 
https://www.raywenderlich.com/60749/grand-central-dispatch-in-depth-part-1

This would optimize the number of threads according to the device capabilibilities  and eliminate  unnecessary thread allocations. You would need Concurrent queue.
The simplest(not the most optimized way) is:

```
 dispatch_async(dispatch_get_global_queue( DISPATCH_QUEUE_PRIORITY_DEFAULT, 0), ^{
     // do your task here
  });
```

For more information check the  previously mentioned article.

Comment: While this link may answer the question, it is better to include the essential parts of the answer here and provide the link for reference.  Link-only answers can become invalid if the linked page changes. - [From Review](/review/low-quality-posts/13051275)

Comment: You are right I will edit it in a minute with the simplest solution.